# Android Macrobenchmark: How to keep the APK on target from being updated

Tags: android, gradle, macrobenchmark

I have an application that requires a user to be logged-in in order to function. Every time I try to launch the Macrobench, it appears that the APK is being built, then deleted on the target, then added, which in-turn needs the user to log in again. Also has the net result that the application takes longer to start than normal, and other nasty side-effects.

Tried to make sure that the signing is the same in Gradle. Tried using the Benchmarked APK to sign in (this removes the signing key dependency) - that did not work. Since the application gets deleted (or so it disappears and then later reappears sometime later.)

Comment: When uninstalling an app there is an option to keep the data so technically you could avoid the login procedure every time. However I am not familiar with Macrobench if it allows to make use of this option.